# Rendering a content type with Views, in Drupal 7

Tags: views, nodes

I have 3 content types and I'd like to render two of them using Views. But there is not option when I can mark this 2 types. 
I can mark "show all," "show first type," or "show second type," but I can't choose 2 of 3 types.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7):

To create a list of two content types in Views you can't set it directly in the 'wizard'. For now just select 'All', at the bottom click 'Continue & Edit'. To only show two content types go down to 'Filter Criteria' and click 'Add'. Find 'Content: Type' in the list and check it, then click 'Add and configure filter criteria'. This will allow you to select the content types you'd like to show. Finally click 'Apply'.

Comment: Did you find your answer @AndrewSmith ?